# Replacing sequence of row values in R

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, time-series

I am trying to replace a sequence of rows based on the previous and next status in the rows. Let's say I have three factors namely 'Control', 'Fan' and 'Compressor' in a time-series data. If the factor 'Fan' appears between 'Control' and 'Compressor', then I wanted to change the factor 'Fan' to 'Compressor'.

For example, In the below table, I wanted to replace 'Fan' with 'Control'. Note: In the original, column 'Status' contained 'character'. I tried converting the characters to factors, thinking it might help solve the problem. So does not matter if the desired output is a character or factor.

| Status |
| --- |
|  |
| Control |
| Control |
| Fan |
| Fan |
| Fan |
| Compressor |
| Compressor |

Desired output:

| Status |
| --- |
|  |
| Control |
| Control |
| Compressor |
| Compressor |
| Compressor |
| Compressor |
| Compressor |

Thanks.

I tried the following,

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df))
  df$Status[i]<- ifelse(df$Status[i]=='Fan' && df$Status[i+1]=='Compressor',
                                  "Compressor",df$Status_change1[i])
```

But this only replaces the value in one row.

The output I got with the above code:

| Status |
| --- |
|  |
| Control |
| Control |
| Fan |
| Fan |
| Compressor |
| Compressor |
| Compressor |

I am struck in finding the next time/episode when the status ' Compressor' occurs.

Comment: What if `FAN` is between control and control? or compressor and compressor? or compressor and control??

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu, Thanks. If 'FAN' is between 'CONTROL' and 'CONTROL' or 'Compressor' and 'Control', I do not want to change the sequence. Only if 'FAN' occurred between 'Control' and 'Compressor', I want to replace 'FAN' with 'COMPRESSOR'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, I think this works as well just looping compressor locations, finding elements between fans and replacing. Great answer above.

```
library(dplyr)
Test <- data.frame(Status = c("Control", "Control", "Fan", "Fan", "Compressor", "Fan", "Fan",
                              "Control", "Control", "Fan", "Fan", "Fan", "Compressor", "Fan"))

LocateFans <- which(Test$Status == "Fan", arr.ind = T)
LocateComp <- which(Test$Status == "Compressor", arr.ind = T)
LocateControl <- which(Test$Status == "Control", arr.ind = T)


for(i in LocateControl) {
  NextCompressor <- LocateComp[LocateComp > i]
  Fans <- which(between(LocateFans, i, min(NextCompressor)))
  Test$Status[LocateFans[Fans]] <- "Compressor"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be handled robustly using run-length encoding.

```r
quux <- structure(list(Status = c("Control", "Control", "Fan", "Fan", "Fan", "Compressor", "Compressor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
r <- rle(quux$Status)
r
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:3] 2 3 2
#   values : chr [1:3] "Control" "Fan" "Compressor"
ind <- r$values == "Fan" &
  c(FALSE, r$values[-length(r$values)] == "Control") &
  c(r$values[-1] == "Compressor", FALSE)
ind
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
r$values[ind] <- "Compressor"
quux$newStatus <- inverse.rle(r)
quux
#       Status  newStatus
# 1    Control    Control
# 2    Control    Control
# 3        Fan Compressor
# 4        Fan Compressor
# 5        Fan Compressor
# 6 Compressor Compressor
# 7 Compressor Compressor
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively with Tidyverse:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- tibble(Status = c(rep("Control",2),
                      rep("Fan",3),
                      rep("Compressor",2)))
df
#> # A tibble: 7 × 1
#>   Status    
#>   <chr>     
#> 1 Control   
#> 2 Control   
#> 3 Fan       
#> 4 Fan       
#> 5 Fan       
#> 6 Compressor
#> 7 Compressor

df %>% 
  nest(.by = Status) %>% 
  filter(!(Status == "Fan" & 
         lag(Status) == "Control" &  
         lead(Status) == "Compressor")) %>% 
  unnest(data)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>   Status    
#>   <chr>     
#> 1 Control   
#> 2 Control   
#> 3 Compressor
#> 4 Compressor
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>